# Looking for duplicates in columns between 2 dataframes in pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, compare

How would I be able to write a function that detects if there are duplicates of a pandas Dataframe. So if I compare the `index` column between `first` and `second` there are no duplicates. But if I compare the `index` column between `first` and `third` there are duplicates of `1`. I want to write a function that returns a `bool` of True when there are duplicates and a `False` when there aren't.

```
import pandas as pd

first = pd.DataFrame({'index': [1,4,5,6],
                      'vals':[3,4,5,7] })

second = pd.DataFrame({'index': [13,7,8,9],
                      'vals':[3,2,3,1] })

third = pd.DataFrame({'index': [1,11,2,12],
                      'vals':[6,7,51,2] })
```

Expected Output:

```
first and second: False
first and third: True
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what went wrong with your attempts? Please [edit] to include a [mcve] with a sample of your code attempts

Comment: `first` and `second` share the index `6`. Why is the expected output `False`?

Comment: sorry made a mistake fixed it now

Comment: OK, try `any(first['index'].isin(second['index']))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sets` predicate:

```
>>> any(set(first['index']).intersection(second['index']))
False  # because {}

>>> any(set(first['index']).intersection(third['index']))
True  # because {1}
```